# sharpsvn: Creating a file remotely

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

Is there any way to create a file using sharpsvn remotely? I mean without using a file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without a file system. It is however possible to do this using the `SvnClient.Import` call, which corresponds to the `svn import` command. This does need the filesystem, but doesn't require you to create a working copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not straightforward. However you can use a trick like this. For directories you can use `client.RemoteCreateDirectory(uri)` which is exactly what you want. For files, first keep the files you want to create in a remote directory (not the best solution though), then call `client.RemoteCopy()` method. However there is no straightforward method to upload a file, lets say from a stream.